# build json from nested dataframe in r

Tags: r, json, dataframe, nested

I'm struggling with building a json.

I have a dataframe with 3 rows, and two columns: "id" (a list of ids), and then "text" (tweets).

```
df$id= c(78198310004451, 78198310004451, 88198310004453)
df$text = c("I love you", "I just got married!", "I just got a new job!")

and four other fixed variables whose values are static:
Models = c(1:7)
orgId= 1
and two attributes of the twitter id
include_outcome: logi FALSE
twitterId = 70051429
```

I pulled down the template json and converted it into a dataframe (see below), for an example of 3 tweets.

I cannot figure out how to generate such a dataframe from my pre-existing data frame i mentioned above (which i will then convert to json (toJSON) ).

```
List of 3
 $ Models: num [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 $ orgId       : num 1
 $ userData    :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ tweets           :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ text: chr "I love you"
  .. .. .. ..$ id  : num 78198310004451
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ text: chr "I just got married!"
  .. .. .. ..$ id  : num 78198310004452
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ text: chr "I just got a new job!"
  .. .. .. ..$ id  : num 88198310004453
  .. ..$ twitterId        : num 70051429
  .. ..$ include_outcome: logi FALSE
```

here's the dput output

````
list(Models = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), orgId = 1, userData = list(
    list(tweets = list(list(text = "I love you", id = 78198310004451), 
        list(text = "I just got married!", id = 78198310004452), 
        list(text = "I just got a new job!", id = 88198310004453)), 
    twitterId = 70051429, include_outcome = FALSE)))```
````

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and your expected output

Comment: i'm not familiar with dput, and i'm not sure what you want me to reproduce?i'm asking how to build a dataframe that can make the above output from a dataframe of, in this case, 3 rows (three ids, and three text), and other two (Models and orgID are just seperate lists). i'm not sure what there is to reproduce?

Comment: ah, dput is pretty cool (still not sure what it does). i added the dput output.

Comment: isn't this a `list` and not `data.frame`

Comment: i guess it is a list of lists.  you're right. i'm not sure how to recreate this from the two column dataframe of ids and tweets. (the real dataframe will be 100s long, hence i want to automatically construct this)

Comment: so you want to create this structure from another dataset?

Comment: yes. based upon the presented core dataframe of 2 cols and 2 rows (but in actuality it will be 100s of rows for that single twitter id (70051429) ).